# Can I add time delay in a string in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, python-multithreading

I know we can print line by line in a loop and after one line we can add something like time.sleep(0.5). But I want to return a string from a function which has time delay built-in in it.

e.g.

```
s = 'I love my dog' + sleep(0.5) + 'I also love my cat'
print(s)
```

this will print 'I love my dog' and after 0.5 sec it will print 'I also love my cat'.

Comment: A string is just a sequence of characters. It's not a little program that can do anything you want.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Why not wirte a function that take a string and a time_interval as parameters, which then loops throgh all letters and prints them with a timeout?

Comment: You could do something like `my_tuple = 'I love my dog', functools.partial(sleep, 5), 'I also love my cat'`  but it doesn't really feel right or necessary to me

Answer (score 0):

From IDLE:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(0.5)
>>> s = "asdf" + time.sleep(0.5) + "asdf"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    s = "asdf" + time.sleep(0.5) + "asdf"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

So, in short, not in that way. But, the following works in that it's a single item to return (kind of):

```
>>> x = (print("asdf"), time.sleep(0.5), print("asdf"))
asdf
asdf
>>> x
(None, None, None)
>>>
```

A better method might be to return a tuple of `(list of strings, time interval)` which can be passed to another function for printing.

Comment: Why are you assigning those output values to anything?

Comment: That's what I tend to do whenever trying something in IDLE. In this case, it might show that the operation has a return type (in case someone is trying to return the item)

Comment: If you don't make the assignment, python will print the result for you anyway if it's not None

Comment: I'm aware, but this is just my preference.

Comment: But that does the time delay when the tuple is being constructed, not when the strings are being printed.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't *exactly* what you are asking for, this might be the effect you are looking for:

```
from time import sleep

s1 = 'I love my dog'
s2 = ' I also love my cat'

print(s1, end='', flush=True)
sleep(2)
print(s2)
```

This will get both sentences on the same line, the second one after a `2` second delay.

Answer (score 0):

## Python Type-writer Effect

For every letter in the string, my answer provides 0.1 of a second to wait, so the text would appear one by one. Code:

```
def anything(str):
for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
anything("Blah Blah Blah...")
```